# Center text inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, positioning, center, centering

I have been stuck with this annoying issue that I have...I cannot center a text inside a div.

I managed to get the text to BEGIN at the center, but I want the text in whole to be centered.

Here is my example - any tips and tricks are VERY appreciated.

```css
#box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px -225px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#TEXT {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p id="TEXT">This text is not centered</p>
</div>
```

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/y97myrap/

Comment: Rather than editing the question you can "accept" an answer to show people which one solved it for you.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

use `text-align:center;`, this will work if you give `width` to the concerned `div`....

Make `div` `100%` wide, then `text-align:center;` will push everything in center

```css
#box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -225px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#TEXT {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    <!-- left: 50% -->
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <p id="TEXT">This text is not centered</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     <div style="text-align:center;">
        data is here 
     </div>
```

in html5

Comment: **1.** This is not HTML5 **2.** OP has `Absolute` elements, so this would not work **3.** Inline CSS is generally not suggested! :)

Comment: btw...your DP...is that GOHAN or GOTENKS?

Comment: it is Gohan not gotenks

Comment: thought so...big fan!! :)

Comment: same here but no new event or any serial or movie from them ........ disappointed............ :(

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `position: absolute;` from `#TEXT`

http://jsfiddle.net/y97myrap/4/

Answer (score 0):

Fot centering an element using position absolute, the common way is set:

```
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin left:{Minus half of the width of the element you want to center}
```

So, my suggestion for you case is the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/y97myrap/1/

using an outside container div and then adding text-align to that one,
and if you want to center the height as well, if the parent height is fixed you can just use a line height on the text the same height as the container, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/y97myrap/5/

Answer (score 0):

```
#TEXT {
   position: relative;
   top:20%
}
```

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/y97myrap/2/)

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple matter of applying a negative top margin of half the images height, and a negative left margin of half the width.

Code:

```
#box {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
}
```

It will make the position of the object fixed, you can adjust the positions of the div as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` tecnique. Add `table` in container and `table-cell` in child element:

```css
#box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -225px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table;/*Add display table*/
}
#TEXT {
    display: table-cell;/*Add display table cell*/
    vertical-align: middle;/*add vertical-align middle*/
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <p id="TEXT">This text is not centered</p>
</div>
```

Comment: **Caution :** IE8+ supported!

Comment: I hope people don not support IE8-- any more :)

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your fiddle is that you have position:absolute; and a left of 50%...I'm guessing u tried to center it this way, but the problem is the text block will start after 50%. Remove position, give it text-align:center;.

And to align it vertically consider using table cells

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position:absolute and just add auto margings to your #TEXT:

```
    #TEXT {
  top: 30px;
  left: 50%
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code solved it:

```
#TEXT {
position: relative;
display: block;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
top: 30px;
}
```